# Algorithm for minimizing schedule collisions for conferences

Tags: algorithm

Is there any known algorithm hat could solve the following problem:
We have a conference with multiple simultaneous talks. The users should mark the talks of interest and then we want to create a schedule of the talks so that my most people can go to their talks and minimizing schedule collisions.

Is this similar to any known problem that has a known solution algorithm?

Comment: This is one variant of the well known "Job Shop Scheduling" problems, dig with it...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an NP-complete problem since the search space grows exponentially with number of rooms and lectures.

I think you can come up with some greedy algorithm which would produce feasible albeit likely not optimal solution.

I thought about it for a moment and came up with the algorithm bellow. Suggestions, improvements, other algorithms are welcome:)

Let's say there are `m` rooms, `l` slots in each room, slots are aligned and there are `n` participants. There will be then at most `m`*`l` lectures. I would create a complete graph with `# of lectures` vertices where edges will have weights computed from participant preferences. I'll ask participants to provide an ordered list of lectures. I'll assign some value to every position - for instance 20 to the first and 1 to the last. Then for every participant I'll take his ordering and for lecture `a` I'll add to every adjacent edge the position value minus position value of the opposite node.

This explanation sounds a bit inadequate so let's have an example. There are four nodes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. The participant orders them in alphabetic order. 1. means 20 points, 2. -> 10 pts, 3. -> 5 pts, 4. -> 0 pts. So the line between `a` and `b` will have 10 pts. between `a` and `d` 20 points.

This graph then represents relations between lectures. The smaller the value the more important it is to have the two lectures happen in different times. Or the other way around the higher it is the better to put them at the same time to different rooms.

Now we need to find minimum `m` disjunct paths of length `l` to assign every room `mx` a set of lectures. That is difficult (without a proof:)). Now it is time to come up with a greedy algorithm to find some local minimum. We can use for instance Kruscal algorithm (or rather Prim's since the graph is going to be rather dense) to find the minimum spanning tree and then find a min. path of length `l`. Then we remove path's nodes assigning them to room `m1`. Find the min. spanning tree in the new graph. Repeat in total `m` times.

The solution does not have to be optimal since the sum of `m` min paths may be lower if construct them using say two edges from the first minimal path so the algorithm won't find the optimal solution.

I'm interested in your thoughts.